# Rolling 6 Months dates in oracle

Tags: oracle

I wanna roll six months dates starting from 2016 to current date, output should be like below

```
 Year   Start_Date    End_Date
 2016   1/1/2016      30/6/2016
 2016   1/7/2016      31/12/2016
 2017   ... like this for 2017 & 2018
```

I tried like fetch first date of the year like

```
SELECT TRUNC(to_date(Date_key, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YEAR')  
FROM Table;
```

and adding six months from first date, but in this case end date will be problem. Is there a function I can do this without loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select extract (year from add_months (date '2016-01-01', (level - 1) * 6)) year,
  2         add_months (date '2016-01-01', (level - 1) * 6) start_date,
  3         add_months (date '2016-01-01', (level) * 6) - 1 end_date
  4  from dual
  5  connect by level <= (extract (year from sysdate) - 2016 + 1) * 2;

      YEAR START_DATE END_DATE
---------- ---------- ----------
      2016 01.01.2016 30.06.2016
      2016 01.07.2016 31.12.2016
      2017 01.01.2017 30.06.2017
      2017 01.07.2017 31.12.2017
      2018 01.01.2018 30.06.2018
      2018 01.07.2018 31.12.2018

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this,

```
SELECT :p_from_year + CEIL(ROWNUM/2)-1,
    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:p_from_year + CEIL(rownum/2)-1, 'YYYY'), 'YYYY'),6-(MOD(rownum, 2)*6)) from_date,
    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(:p_from_year + CEIL(rownum/2)-1, 'YYYY'), 'YYYY'),12-(MOD(rownum, 2)*6))-1 to_date
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY CEIL(rownum/2)-1 <= (:p_to_year - :p_from_year)
```